# Can anyone please explain events in a way that I can understand?

Tags: c#, events

I have been programming for about 2 months now and I'm self-learned, while I get the basics about inheritance, polymorphism, interfaces, delegates, data & reference types, loops, if/switch, LINQ, xml, SQL, etc etc. I just cannot wrap my head around events!

I have read at least 4-5 different tutorials and writeups online but they are way too confusing to me, there's an Event type, EventHandler, delegates, event raise/subscribe, there's just too much stuff going on and, I don't know if I'm thickheaded or not but it's INCREDIBLY confusing for me.

Please explain events to me in a way that a complete beginner programmer like me can understand, many thanks!

Comment: You are on the wrong site. SO is a Q&A site on real coding problems.

Comment: An event is similar to an action that somebody can respond to.  If I fall down (event), you can help me stand up (handler).  As a beginner it is best to focus on high level understanding of concepts.  Do not get lost in the forest of details and similarities with other technologies such as delegates or design patters etc.

Comment: Event-driven programming is confusing because the program doesn't always have a start or end that is visible to the programmer. Behind the scenes, the actual code is still running sequentially, but all you have to worry about as a developer is "When I click this button, this code executes." Your development environment takes care of the rest.

Comment: Set realistic goals, you can't understand events in two months.  Unless you buy a brain transplant, we are not a donor site.

Comment: I could explain it to you in terms of "The Observer Pattern", but you've only been programming for two months, so design patterns a probably a bit over your head at the moment".

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to try and understand events at this point, is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't get much simpler than this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

At their core event simply contain a list of functions (or at least a way to access these functions) which will be called the event is raised. Raising an event is simply the act of triggering the subject to notify all the functions which are subscribed (read: contained in the list) to that event.

How this list of subscriptions is comprised varies greatly depending on the capabilities of the framework. In the observer pattern (commonly used in Java) you do this by passing in an object that has implemented the appropriate interface. The subject iterates through the list of observers and call the function defined by the interface. The drawback to this pattern is that you have to have the potential for a naming collision between two entirely different subjects which can be difficult (though not impossible) to work around.

Delegates remedy this issue by allowing you to pass in the function or method itself. A delegate is sort of like an interface in that it establishes a contract but instead of class members it just specifies a set of parameters for a function. The subject can then iterate through a list of these methods, which are commonly referred to as event handlers, and pass the appropriate parameters. Delegates are less troublesome than an observer pattern but they can still be time consuming.

More recently C# added the generic delegates [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which are a bit easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Action and reaction.

As John said in your comments.. "When I click a button, something happens!"